# opencv python3.6 OCR

Tags: python, opencv

I do not know openCV but I would like to know 
[Area extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbTr9.png)

If the white area is reduced by hsv, the text is broken and can not be recognised. If there is a white area, THRESH_BINARY_INV is converted as shown above.

I would appreciate your help.

I set out to solve this problem.

I do not know if this is being interpreted properly.

My code will be attached [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbTr9.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def tracking():
     frame = cv2.imread('test4.png')

     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

     lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
     upper = np.array([255, 255, 240])
     mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

     res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
     cv2.imshow('asdasd2', res2)
     _, edge2 = cv2.threshold(res2, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
     cv2.imshow('asdasd2', edge2)  

     cv2.imshow('original', frame)
     cv2.imshow('finish', res2)

     cv2.waitKey(0)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tracking()
```

Comment: What you want from those images ? do you want to read text from those images? Or you want to convert those images to a new image with white background ?

Comment: Yes!! I want to leave only "DWSWDDA" so that only the letter part can be extracted from the image above.

Comment: then try it by using [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) or [tesserocr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr) it might help you!